# UnityWebRequest data is blank

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I am using a flask server and having Unity access it. Testing it in Postman (with platform:test) gives me `ImmutableMultiDict([('platform', 'test')])` (result of request.form in Flask) which works. But when unity makes a post request (code provided), it gives me `ImmutableMultiDict([])`. I'm not completely sure if this is a Unity or a Flask problem. Help is much appreciated.

```
IEnumerator PostRequest(string url)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("platform", "test");

    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
    uwr.uploadHandler.contentType = "multipart/form-data";
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
Unity formats its data wildly different from PostMan, and my Flask server couldn't read it. Instead of using `request.form[key]` or `request.data[key]` in Flask, I found `request.form.getlist(key)` worked perfectly with both Postman's requests and Unity's.